# Is my internet connection too slow for online games?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When playing Modern Warfare 3 (PS3), it seems like I'm killed by a single bullet constantly.  When I watch the kill cam, it looks like the other player shot me 4-5 times.  Is my internet connection too slow?

Running a speed test averages 55ms ping, 24 Mbps down, and 1 Mbps up.  The PS3 is connected via hardline (Cat6) to my router, so there shouldn't be too much speed loss on the intranet.

What can I do to make my multi-player experience more enjoyable?

Comment: It's more likely that the host of the game isn't fast enough to you (being the console version).

Comment: 55ms ping is actually a bit high, but it shouldn't be unplayable

Comment: Wow i thought I was the only one with this issue. I'm about to loose my mind trying to figure out why I can't get in a 50ms game, always getting 75ms or higher. I have 50/10 dwn/up mb cant get host in MW3 (was able too in BOPS) and have the same issues as described above. Getting killed when I seem to have the drop on opponents. I work in IT so I know about router settings, tried it all. finally left PS3 in DMZ . If this doesn't get better I may dump this game by Xmas.

Comment: Do you have roommates running bittorrent all day? A high ping on an otherwise fast connection seems odd. If this is the case, your router may support "Quality of Service" (QoS) which would let you decrease your latency without a major effect on your roommates downloads.

Answer (score 7):

Probably the opposite, i.e. your connection is too good and you are being screwed by the 'lag compensation' logic that Activision has seen fit to implement. I have a 50Mb down, 5Mb up and typically get 15ms or less on speedtest.net and MW3 is unplayable for me either as host or when another player is host.

Google 'lag compensation' and check out the blogs as there are many other people experiencing the same problem.

If Activision don't sort this out then they'll never get my business again. MW2 was OK, Black Ops was bad but MW3 is the worst online experience I've ever had!

Comment: This is a very good possibility. If you strongly believe it's lag compensation, you can configure your router to only give your the console so much bandwidth. I've tried this and it makes a small difference and wouldn't really recommend it. Also, I think their lag compensation is similar to MW2 (ie, OK) and not Black Ops. I haven't seen a ton of lagging like I did in Black Ops

Comment: I too have a router that enables me to limit upload bandwidth and found that a value of between 500-750kbps can improve things. It does not ix the problem as is does not change your ping but at least you can get games that are just about playable albeit very frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

There are many factors to consider when talking about lag:

- Is it graphics lag?
- Is it Network lag?
- Is it server lag?
- Is it remote player lag due to any of the above on there end
- Is it network congestion at some remote point in your line

All these (and more) must be asked when trying to determine reason for lag in any game.

How do you make it better? Rule out what you can on your end and work backwards from there.

- 24 Mbps is plenty to play online
- 55 ms ping is quite good
- 1 Mbps up is ok but should not hurt your connection

Next thing to ask:

- Is anyone else in your location uploading large amount of data while you play? (Going to have to be gigs worth to make it noticed)
- Is someone downloading/streaming at a high resolution (i.e 720p or 1080p on youtube)
- Are there certain times of day when the problem happens or is it every time?
- Is your connection cable? If so how big is your neighborhood and how many are using the same cable connection at the same time?

Due to this being a gaming site we'll be unable to answer the rest of the questions here, I'd recommend you search for specifics or ask over at superusers.com (part of stackexchange)